# Compare JSON key values

Tags: json, karate

```
How to Compare two JSON structure and return the result. We are able to compare the keys but not the key values.
```

- def result = karate.match(result1,result2).pass ? { pass: true } : { pass: false}
- print result

Is there any way to compare structure of two json and print the result.